# NumberFormatter generate unbreakable space

Tags: php

I try to put a formated currency input from php as value of an input,

```
$format = numfmt_create( 'fr_FR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$datavalue = numfmt_format_currency($format, $data['value'], 'EUR');
```

It works, but the result contain unbreakable space caracter like so

```
value='10,0&nbsp;€'
```

That lead to mess up with my design, I didn't found how to remove it yet

Already tried :

```
str_replace('&nbsp;', " ", $datavalue);
```

Comment: `str_replace('&nbsp;', " ", $datavalue);`

Comment: Sorry, I frogot to tell that I already tried that :(

Comment: Sounds like it is being changed after it sent to the browser. Have you verified the value of `$datavalue` within the php script itself?

Comment: Or try `echo "this is a test";` to see if those spaces are converted in the browser as well.

Comment: Maybe see http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.settextattribute.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Run the result through [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) then perform your `str_replace(' ', '', $datavalue);`</s>

That [class/function](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) prefers an integer be passed to it, so you need to clean up your data before you ever get to the function.

Comment: Then I'm guessing the problem is with the data you are putting into it.  What is the result of ``var_dump($data['value'])``? Also, is your script  Encoded in UTF8?  In Notepad++ you can check this under the **Encoding** menu option.

Comment: yes it is in UTF8, the var_dump gave me 
<pre class="xdebug-var-dump" dir="ltr"><small>C:\wamp\www\compat\former.php:91:</small><small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'0,00&nbsp;€'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
</pre>

Comment: So that's your problem @Richard . That class/function expects an **Integer** be passed to it, so you need to clean up your data before you ever get to the function.

Comment: Yes you're right, if I make my var an integer it works. But don't say numfmt_format_currency wait for an integer because it's false ;) it will just change the format of the output. Anyway, can you edit your original answer so I give you the green check ^^

Comment: Your edit must look more like "if you put a real integer as input, you'll get no extra characters (such as spaces) in the output" And not the "it expects an integer" because it's not true

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
str_replace("\xc2\xa0", ' ', $datavalue);
```

Where \xc2\xa0 is the unicode for non-breaking space.
Make sure you use double quotes for the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)

example:

```
$amount = '12345.67';
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('fr_FR',  NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo 'format: ', $formatter->formatCurrency($amount, 'EUR'), PHP_EOL;
   //output 
     12 345,67 €
```

**edit:** other method is use this [MoneyFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)
example

```
$number = 1234.56;

// let's print the international format for the en_US locale
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
// USD 1,234.56
```

Comment: Same result (that is just the same thing btw)

Comment: That work, except that my client use a windows syste that don't use this function

Comment: money_format is REMOVED as of PHP 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

```
$amount = '12345.67';
$fmt= new NumberFormatter('en_IN',  NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$fmt->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::FRACTION_DIGITS, 0);
$fmt->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, '');
$fmt->setPattern("#,##,##0");
return $fmt->formatCurrency(floatval($amount), 'INR');
```

it will return formatted amount without any space and without any currency symbol

Answer (score 0):

In my testing I found that it is not the `NBSP` character, but the `NNBSP` character.

- `NBSP`: `NO-BRAKE-SPACE`, UTF-8 `0xC2 0xA0` or UTF-16 `0x00A0`
- `NNBSP`: `NARROW NO-BRAKE-SPACE`, UTF-8 `0xE2 0x80 0xAF` or UTF-16 `0x202F`

It can be removed like this:

```php
str_replace("\u{202F}", "", $string);
```